# How to solve this differential equation non separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve that, but I am getting in anywhere. I know to solve separating  and applying Integral, but in this case I cannot separate, so I couldn't. Please help me guys.

$$(4y+yt^2)dy - (2t+ty^2)dt = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;
$$(4y+yt^2)dy - (2t+ty^2)dt = 0$$
$$y(4+t^2)dy - t(2+y^2)dt = 0$$

$$ydy - \frac{t(2+y^2)}{4+t^2}dt = 0$$
$$\frac{y}{2+y^2}dy - \frac{t}{4+t^2}dt = 0$$

which has separated the variables.

From what you say, that was the issue.

Can you do it now ?

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not try enough. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome; I'm pleased it has helped.